# Why do different multimeters give me very different current measurements?

Tags: current, current-measurement, multimeter

I was trying to calculate R_TH using an open-circuit voltage and a short-circuit current, and I am having trouble with the current measurement. I noticed that my calculated R_TH didn’t match my measured value.

I’ve tried 3 different multimeters and on all of them, my voltage and resistance values are consistent, but my current values are all completely different. I checked the fuses and there doesn’t seem to be anything wrong with the multimeters. Any idea on what I’m doing wrong?

The cheapest multimeter is the only one that appears to give a valid current reading (based on the voltage and resistance values). I got 0.96 mA with a DT830B multimeter (unsure of the brand), 1.3 mA with a Mastfuyi FY8233E multimeter, and 2.47 mA with a Klein MM400 multimeter.

The reason I don't have the blue one on the 60 mA setting is because it was giving 14.88 mA, which was wayyyy off. I don’t know why it was doing that either .

I’ve attached images below of the multimeters I used:

[image: DT830B Multimeter]

[image: Mastfuyi FY8233E Multimeter]

[image: Klein MM400 Multimeter]

Comment: What's the burden voltage of those multimeters?

Comment: @Hearth I don't believe it is specified in the first case shown, for example. See [this](https://www.all-sun.com/manual/Dt830_en.pdf), though, as I may be missing something. It's a reason to have an analog meter on hand.

Comment: One factor is you are using different ranges for measuring. The lower the range, the more accurate the result (if the multimeter is calibrated). Also, could you put all three multimeters in series and measure at the same time? The multimeters could have different resistance and you might end up with different current values. By making them series, you can be sure they are experiencing the same current.

Comment: Try connecting the three meters in series, so you will know that the same current is flowing through all three meters.  The meters then should read the same (+/- a count or two).  If they don't read the same, one or more is out of calibration.

Comment: So, this might be a silly question. How do I calibrate a multimeter?

Comment: @SamanthaGarcia "How do I calibrate a multimeter?"  Generally YOU don't, you send it to a calibration lab where they calibrate it to a very expensive standard.  If you know your meter is out of calibration and you can find a calibration procedure (non-existant for cheap meters) , you could conceivably calibrate to a known good meter.

Comment: Samantha, For your DT830B meter, giving **0.96mA**...if you switch from 20mA scale to 2000uA scale, you should now get **960uA**. I'll bet you don't. And if you switch to 200mA scale, you should now get **.9mA** or possibly **1.0mA**. I'll bet you don't. Some of the variation results from internal calibration, but much variation is likely due to the burden problem outlined by some answers.

Comment: Put all three meters in series so they will all be passing the same current. That will allow you yo check they are all calibrated the same.

Comment: Use the lowest possible range on each meter and come back with what you measure.

Comment: @glen_geek actually for the black one, the current is consistent and is giving correct values even for different ranges

Comment: Samantha, Seems I've accused the innocent one: treasure it! Been doing these kind of measurements for decades and have always found current measurements give the most trouble, whereas voltage measurements generally go much better. Even with fuses, current meters take much more abuse than voltmeters. The geek in me would want to peek inside Mastfuyi FY8233E looking for overheated shunt resistors or dirty selector switch.

Comment: @glen_geek I might as well take it apart and take a peek, given it isn't working properly and I have two that do - I double checked the fuse on the Klein and it is not working fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These multimeters measure current by actually measuring *voltage* a cross a resistor through which the current passes, and applying Ohm's law to calculate and display the corresponding current. Here is what you think you're doing, when measuring short-circuit current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKLv7K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is what you are actually doing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMjzjl.png)</sup>

The multimeter is inserting a 100Ω current shunt resistor RM into the current path, and measuring the voltage across it. It would make the following calculation, and display the result:

$$ I = \frac{V_M}{R_M} = \frac{833mV}{100\Omega} = 8.3mA $$

We are taught that ammeters are supposed to have zero resistance between their probes, not 100Ω as I've used here, but sadly that's not the case. Consequently, the multimeter displays only 8.3mA, not the expected 10mA.

I used 100Ω as an example. Different multimeters will use different values, and this resistance also changes depending on the range you selected on the meter. You'll likely get more accurate results (at the cost of precision) by making the measurement on a higher current range, rather than milliamps, because the shunt resistance will be commensurately smaller (by perhaps an order of magnitude) for higher current ranges.

Bear in mind that it's perfectly acceptable, and quite common practice, to perform current measurements in exactly the same way that the multimeter did, but using a shunt resistor of *your* choice.

In the examples above, I can get near 1% accuracy by using a 4.7Ω (1%) resistor that I get out of my component drawer, placing that in the current path, and measuring the voltage across that instead; ironically, using the *same* multimeter in millivolts mode!

Comment: I understand this makes sense, but why when I measure resistance and voltage with the same multimeter, I doesn’t equal V/R? Shouldn’t it use the same internal resistance as it does with current?

Comment: @SamanthaGarcia there's no shunt resistor when measuring voltage. It only inserts a shunt resistance when measuring current. And \$I=\frac{V}{R}\$ always. A multimeter can *only* measure volts, really, it just does clever things to convert into volts first, and then do the maths to show something else.

Comment: A digital multimeter measures everything by converting to voltage, but an analog multimeter converts everything to current.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is each one of your meters has a different internal shunt resistance (and that can also change with the range). You see, inside the DMM there is a shunt resistor (low ohm resistor) for dropping a voltage across it while current passes through it. Then, an amplifier measures this voltage drop to calculate the current. The point is, this shunt resistance is part or your circuit under test. You may not have a real problem.

Try this: Set all your meters to mA current ranges. Then put them all in series so you are measuring the same loop at the same time. This will remove current variance from meter to meter because that same exact current will be passing through them irrespective on how much voltage they are independently dropping. If your meters are accurate and working properly, they will be statistically close in value. If not, one or more of them are damaged/inaccurate.

Assuming all meters are reading properly, next thing you can do is put only one meter in the current loop and using the other 2 DMMs, measure the voltage drop across the one measuring the current. Repeat this arrangement for the other 2 DMMs. Report your findings.

Comment: It just popped up an interesting question: Can I use one multimeter's Ohm range to measure the shunt in the other multimeter being set to current (Amperes)? ;-)

Comment: @U.Windl (mostly) Yes. You have to account for the resistance of the test leads (trivial). And also a (negligible) bias current from the internal amplifier which, depending on your measuring meter's resolution, can be accounted for by measuring in both directions and taking the average. But the answer is yes if you ignore these higher order effects.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could improve is to choose the smallest possible range. For low cost multimeters, it can significantly improve accuracy :

- black multimeter : your reading is <1mA, so you can switch to 2000µA=2mA range (I don't expect much difference, but still, it's free to do so)
- blue multimeter : you are currently on 600mA while reading 1.3mA : this is less than 0.3% of full range : expect very unprecise mesurement (excepted if you have a very high end multimeter, and even then it's best to choose the right range). The smallest range you have is 60mA : not great, but alreaddy far better.
- orange Multimeter : it is a auto-ranging one, so I expect it to be already on the right range

Not sure if this is the reason of the different readings (it might account for quite some error on the blue multimeter, but not for the factor 2.5 between the black and the orange ones).

Comment: In English, we would say "range", rather than "caliber".

Comment: thanks. Corrected

Comment: The reason the blue one was measured like that was because 60m gave me 14.xx mA, which was way off. I don’t know why

Comment: Then this hints strongly that the issue is with the internal shunt resistance as several other answers suggest.

Comment: Considering https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/698648/282833 I wonder: Wouldn't "smaller range" mean "higher resistance for the shunt" (assuming the range if measured voltage remains fixed (constant))? That way wouldn't it have the adverse effect?

Comment: reading a small voltage precisely is hard. Si so for a small current range, we use a bigger resistor, in such way that the voltage U=R*I remains in the optimal range. So if your current range is 10 times smaller, you use a 10 times bigger resistor.

Answer (score 2):

> I was trying to calculate [the Thevenin equivalent resistance] using an open circuit voltage and short circuit current

A low-cost multimeter's low-range current shunt is far from a short circuit. You have to post-process the measurement, based on the burden voltage, i.e. the voltage across the non-ideal "short circuit" that the multimeter's shunt represents.

The two measurements you're performing look as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsKdZK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, the non-zero burden voltage of a real multimeter's current shunt has to be measured in-circuit and subtracted from Voc measured using VM1. The burden voltage is current-dependent, so it must be measured in-circuit. Out-of-circuit burden voltage will be zero.

Also note that the Rmeter is the shunt resistance of a voltmeter circuit in a multimeter. Typical nominal values are either 1MΩ or 10MΩ, but that's not always the case. Some multimeters have a high-impedance mode where Rmeter is on the order of giga-ohms. Analog multimeters have resistance that scales with voltage, say 20kΩ/V may be typical.

The reason for the burden voltage is that the "short circuit" of a multimeter is very much a non-zero resistance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP4ZBU.png)</sup>

The exact value of Rshunt depends on the multimeter and on the chosen measurement range. You can measure it using an ohmmeter attached across the current input, as long as auto-ranging is disabled (i.e. you've manually chosen the measurement range).

Answer (score 0):

You are using different multimeters with different input properties, and these input properties also depends on the used range on each multimeter and you use different ranges. You will find the parameters in the multimeter manuals.

Also you are using a breadboard so it might be that some connections are loose and not all resistors make good contact.